# How to have separate URLs for each controller when creating Web API documentation using Swashbuckle Swagger?

Tags: .net, swagger, webapi, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle Swagger in my Web API project. By default all the controllers are listed on the same page?

[image]

Is there any way that I can have separate URLs for each controller, and each URL would only show operations for that controller?

Comment: I don't think there is an out of the box solution for your requirement. You can however take the original [swagger ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and customize it the way you want as described in [this post](http://brazilianldsjag.com/2015/09/04/how-to-add-swagger-ui-to-web-api-2-part-3/).

Answer (score 0):

As option you can put your controller in different directories.

Comment: Ok. I have put my controller cs files in separate folders and there is no change in the output.